# Populating a <select> with data from ajax via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

although I found similar questions the solutions mentioned there wont seem to work for me.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Fetch all the table names of my database with Ajax
2. Fill the Table Names as options with respective values into a select field

How far I've come:

My fetch_devices php script echoes:

["test1","test2","test3"]

```
function FetchDevices(){
alert("Fetching");
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/sql/fetch_devices.php',
    success: function(devices) {
        var elements = Object.keys(devices).length;
        var select = document.getElementById("devices");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        var i = 0;
        while(i < elements)
        {
            option.text= devices[i];
            option.value= devices[i];
            select.appendChild(option);
            i++;
        }

    },
    cache: false
});
```

}

But in the end I only see the last option "test3".....

Why is that happening?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Comment: If you are using happily jQuery to make development easy, why use Javascript in between?

Comment: `var option = document.createElement("option");` should be in `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the same `option`. Aslo make use of [add()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp). Change it to

```
 while(i < elements)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text= devices[i];
        option.value= devices[i];
        select.add(option);
        i++;
    }
```